# JQuery .click(function() not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The following code works in all browsers but IE. I am using IE 9 and I have included the jquery library. Why is the `.click(function()` not working. The code inside the function is never ran.

```
newEntryRow.find('.dispmsg').click(function(){
    alert("this code is not running");
    showEntryById(1);
});
```

Any ideas why this might be happening and any ideas how to fix it. Thanks.

newEntryRow is a clone of li element, but like I said above it works in all other browsers.

Comment: check on your console if `newEntryRow.find('.dispmsg').length` is greater than 0

Comment: can you make a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of it, so we can test?

Comment: this should work assuming newEntryRow is not null. Are you getting any js errors? Can you reproduce this with jsfiddle?

Comment: Post your htm code from where you get the `newEntryRow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that "newEntryRow.find('.dispmsg')" is returning an element. Is ".dispmsg" an a tag? iF it is you may need to call event.preventDefault(). Other than that you can try using .bind() instead.

Comment: This answer only makes sense up to the first sentence =/

Comment: If the element is a link then your click event will need to call event.preventDefault() to stop the default behavior of link element so your code will run.

Answer (score -1):

The `showEntryById` seems to suggest that you are passing `id` value, however digit alone (`1` in your case) isn't valid value for `id`, try using alpha or combination of alphanumeric letters.

Also make sure that `newEntryRow` is a jQuery object, try outputting it on console.

Comment: numeric IDs are valid in HTML5

Comment: But the code doesn't ever reach that point, it doesn't do the alert.

Comment: @ewein: Then it is most probable that `newEntryRow` isn't coming through correctly.

Comment: @Alnitak: I know that but question isn't tagged html5. Because of that though someone has downvoted.

Comment: on any modern browser html == html5.  You made an assertion which is no longer true.  I really doubt the downvote is because of that.

Comment: @Alnitak: yeah but when you use html5 doctype unless otherwise specified in which case html !== html5